# Flask: updating existing data from database

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

For the following model and route, how can I get the page to display the existing data in the database field, in an editable box, with a ‘save changes’ button.

```
# MODEL
class Task(db.Model): #inherits from db>Model
    __tablename__ = "Tasks"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    # datetime, need to work this out
    Title = db.Column(db.String(4096))
    Status = db.Column(db.String(4096))
    Description = db.Column(db.String(4096))
    Priority = db.Column(db.String(4096))
    Assigned_To = db.Column(db.String(4096))

# ROUTE:
@app.route("/<int:task_id>/edit")
def _edit(task_id):
    task = Task.query.get_or_404(task_id)
    return render_template('update.html',task=task)
```

```
<—- update.html—->
<form method="POST" action="">
            <fieldset>
             {{ task.Title }}
             {{ task.Description }}
            </fieldset>
        </form>
```

I would prefer not to define Forms if possible. I have an SQL Alchemy database configured and working.

The routes added to the end of this question are working fine - adding new tasks (rows) to the database and creating individual pages to view individual tasks (rows):

```
@app.route("/tasks", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def new_post():
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render_template("tasks.html")
    data = Task(
        Title=request.form["title"],
        Description=request.form["description"],
        Status=request.form["status"],
        Priority=request.form["priority"],
        Assigned_To=request.form["assigned"],
        )
    db.session.add(data)
    db.session.commit()
    return redirect(url_for('index'))

@app.route("/<int:task_id>")
def qtsk(task_id):
    task = Task.query.get_or_404(task_id)
    return render_template('indtask.html',task=task)
```

I’m new to flask, I would greatly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

I was watching a Flask tutorial recently and this is how he deals with this situation:

```py
@app.route("/post/<int:post_id>/update", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def update_post(post_id):
    post = Post.query.get_or_404(post_id)
    if (post.author != current_user):
        abort(403)
    form = PostForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        post.title = form.title.data
        post.content = form.content.data
        db.session.commit()
        flash('Your post has been updated!', 'success')
        return redirect(url_for('post', post_id=post_id))
    elif request.method == 'GET':
        form.title.data = post.title
        form.content.data = post.content
    return render_template('create_post.html', title="Update Post", 
                            form=form, legend='Update Post')
```

What it does is it checks if the user is submitting the updated title or content using POST method. If the user is then just update the field and then commit it. Otherwise return the template with the title and content field in the form being filled with the current fields in the Post object.

Here's link for that tutorial (this part starts at 25:35): https://youtu.be/u0oDDZrDz9U

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I was  asking  a  simillar question.
I  think you  can update by  using form. It doesnt have to  be presented as  a  form  to  the  user. You  can write  an  html  template that  would not  lokk like  a form,but youneed  a  form  to fetch data. Maybe you  can  use  javascript and  than you  can skip  the  usage of form. I am on to remember  javascrip an  use  it  for  my  app.